# Meteor change value on modal window when editing

Tags: javascript, meteor, modal-dialog

I would like to add 'Edit' function using modal dialog in a meteor app.
In .html I have

```
<template name="edit_deal">
    <button id="edit_btn" class="edit">Edit</button>
    <div id="edit_dialog" title="Edit opportunity">
     {{> Edit }}
    </div>
</template>

<template name="Edit">
 <form class="edit-deal">
    <input type="text" name="cuname" placeholder="Customer Name">
  </form>
</template>
```

in .js I have

```
Template.edit_deal.rendered = function() { 
 $( "#edit_dialog" ).dialog({
  height: 240,
  width: 800,
  modal: true,
  resizable: false,
  autoOpen: false,
  dialogClass: 'no-close add-dialog'
 });
}

Template.edit_deal.events({
 'click #edit_btn': function(event, template) {
 $( "#edit_dialog" ).dialog('open');
 }
});

Template.Edit.events({
 "submit .edit-deal": function (event) {
  event.preventDefault();

  var cuname = event.target.cuname.value;

  Deals.insert({
   customerName: cuname
  });

 }

});
```

In the Template.edit_deal.events I can get the current name, but cannot write it back to the form. How can I change the form value?

Comment: Can you describe what exact behavior are you expecting?

Comment: If I understand you correctly, you want to set the input value for `cuname` on modal open? If that is the case, you could put `$('input[name="cuname"]').val("foo bar");` inside your `#edit_btn` click event.

Comment: @MatthiasEckhart yes, it works. Can you add it as an answer, then I can accept it. Sorry, if my description was not totally clear, this is my 5th day with Meteor, I am quite newbie. Thank you for your reply!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [jQuery's .val()](http://api.jquery.com/val/#val-value) method to set the value of the input field in your modal:

```
Template.edit_deal.events({
    'click #edit_btn': function(event, template) {
        $("#edit_dialog").dialog('open');
        $('input[name="cuname"]').val("foo bar");
    }
});
```

However, I personally prefer to create a helper function which sets the HTML `input` `value` attribute:

```
Template.Edit.helpers({
    cunameValue: function() {
        return "foo bar";
    }
});
```

---

```
<template name="Edit">
    <form class="edit-deal">
        <input type="text" name="cuname" placeholder="Customer Name" value="{{cunameValue}}">
    </form>
</template>
```

Please note that `Template.edit_deal.rendered = function(){};` is deprecated since Meteor version 1.0.4, as a consequence you should use `Template.edit_deal.onRendered(function(){});` instead.

Comment: One more question, I tried this for drop-down menu, but it doesn't work. The [documentation](http://api.jquery.com/val) says so. Any idea?
`$('input[name="quarter"]').val(this.quarter);`

Comment: Please submit a new question with the complete code snippet.